# I want to disable the selected Item from a Drop Down list for the next row's DropDown Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

[image]

The HTML for the form is :

```
<form id="flowform" class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                                            <table id="add-flow-level" class="table table-striped table-borderless" style="width: 100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                <label class="required ">Min Amount</label>
                                                                <input type="text"
                                                                    id="minAmount" name="minAmount" class="form-control min"
                                                                    style="border-radius: 1rem; width: 183px;"
                                                                    maxlength="100" required="required" 
                                                                         />
                                                                    <!-- onfocus = "maxAmountCheck(this.id);"  -->
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                <label class="required ">Max Amount</label>
                                                                <input
                                                                    type="text" id="maxAmount" name="maxAmount"
                                                                    class="form-control max"
                                                                    style="border-radius: 1rem; width: 183px;"
                                                                    maxlength="100" required="required" />
                                                                    <!--  onfocus = "maxAmountCheck(this.id);"/ -->
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                <label class="required">Approver</label>
                                                                <select class="form-control" id="approver" name="approver"
                                                                    style="border-radius: 1rem; width: 183px;"
                                                                    required="required"  >
                                                                    <!--  onfocus = "approverCheck(this.id);" -->
                                                                    <option th:value="0">Select User</option>
                                                                    <option th:each="usersList : ${usersList}"
                                                                        th:value="${usersList.id}"
                                                                        th:utext="${usersList.firstName +' '+ usersList.lastName}" />
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href="#" id="addFlowLevelRow" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left addFlowLevelRow" title="Add Next" style="margin-top: 18px;">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                             </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <label class="control-label col-sm-5" style="margin-top: 8px;"></label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-label-left"
                                                        value="Save" id="submitbtnflow" name="submitbtnflow"
                                                        style="border-radius: 1rem;">
                                                </div>
                                                <p id="msg" style="color: green;"></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

js file

```
var countOfRows =1;
$(".addFlowLevelRow").click(function() {
    var remv = "<a href='#' id='removeFlowLevelRow' class='btn btn-primary btn-label-left removeFlowLevelRow' title='Remove Row' style='margin-top: 33px;'><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";

    var txt = $(this).closest("tr").find('#removeFlowLevelRow').attr('href');

    if (txt == undefined && countOfRows < 5) {
        var newRow = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#add-flow-level").append(remv);
        
        if(countOfRows == 4)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("addFlowLevelRow")[4].style.display = "none";
            console.log("Removal of - button at row = "+countOfRows);
        }
        countOfRows++;
        console.log("Number of row = "+countOfRows);
    }
    
     else if(countOfRows < 5){
            
        var newRow = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#add-flow-level");
        if(countOfRows == 4)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("addFlowLevelRow")[4].style.display = "none";
            console.log("Removal of - button at row = "+countOfRows);
        }
        countOfRows++;
        console.log("Number of row =" +countOfRows);
        
    }
    
    
    
            var input = document.getElementsByClassName('max');
            
            newRow.find('.min').val(input.value);
            newRow.find('.max').val("");
            newRow.find('#approver').val(0);
            

});

$(document).on('click', '#removeFlowLevelRow', function(e) {
    console.log("view----");
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    countOfRows--;
    console.log("After - Button count is = "+countOfRows);
});

$('#approver').on('change', function() {
        alert("alerrt called");
        var select = document.getElementById('approver');
        var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(value);
      var index = value;
      if (index > -1) {
      //  ${usersList}.splice(index, 1);
      }
      alert("ye ky tha"+select.value);
      //return ${usersList};

    });
```

I want that Super Admin to be disabled for the 2nd row and show values other than super Admin in that drop down.
Whenever the user clicks on + button it creates a clone of the row.
I have not created the new row separately but I want the new drop down to not have the value that are selected in the first drop down and this should go till 5 rows.

Comment: You could have an onchange() event handler that detects the selected value in the dropdown and disables it in the following menus- I may be able to write a mock up if you post more of your code

Comment: Please do not post text information as images.  Please edit your question and copy paste the text (html).  And please post more of your html and css and javascript

Comment: @Simeon I have updated the Question with the code of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id's in the DOM should always be unique otherwise it can lead to strange behaviour in the page
so firstly you need to give each row's "approver" `select` element a separate id  e.g. approver0,1,2... (or just remove the id) and instead have a common class for these elements e.g. `"form-control approver"`

Then in your onchange function, loop through the `approver` class and disable the select options that don't appear, here is some psuedo code to start working with

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("approver")

//loop through all approver select elements

for(i in a) { 
 if(a[i] = this) { 

   //do nothing if we loop to the element that has just been changed

  }
 else { 

   //if the approver select isn't the one we've just changed, loop through the options

   options = a[i].childNodes
   for(j in options){
     if(options[j].value = this.value) {

     //if the option matches the one we've just selected disable it

        options[j].setAttribute("disabled")="disabled"
     }
     else { 

     //Otherwise re-enable it so we don't disable all elements by changing the selection

        options[j].removeAttribute("disabled")
     }
 }
```

In this rudimentary example changing the next approver option will overwrite disabling the previous selection so you may need to also keep track of what has been selected in all other drop downs. but hopefully this gets you started